# Weird layout problem with UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, uinavigationcontroller

I've configured a NIB as follows:

[image]

...but when I display this NIB as a modal view controller, it appears on the simulator as:

[image]

I recall seeing this problem a long time ago on a project, but I can no longer remember what I did to fix it. Any idea what I've done wrong here?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score -1):

The class of your Social Settings view controller is set to `UIViewController`. Shouldn't that be `UITableViewController` or a subclass of it?

Comment: I tried changing it: no difference. (And I guess I don't understand: why would that make a difference?)

Comment: Looking again at your screenshots .. it does seem odd that you are using a UIViewController to host a UITableView. It should really be a UITableViewController I think.